# Is the round up of ample Q-divisor ample?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $A$ an ample $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor on $X$.

Is the round up $\ulcorner A\urcorner$ of $A$ ample?

I think it's true. But I do not know how to arrange an argument.

Comment: It's definitely not true, but if the difference between $\langle A \rangle$ and $A$ has nice singularities you can still get some vanishing theorems.  See for instance things like Lazarsfeld's positivity in algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't seem right.  Let $\pi : X \to \mathbb P^2$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb P^2$ at a point, and let $A = L + 2/3 E$, where $E$ is the exceptional divisor, and $L$ is the strict transform of a line through the point.  Take $H$ to be the pullback of a line in $\mathbb P^2$.  Then $A$ is linearly equivalent to $(H-E)+2/3 E = H - 1/3 E$, which is ample.  But the round-up of $A$ is $L+E$, linearly equivalent to $H$, which isn't ample.

Comment: Hi, sorry can you explain why $H-1/3E$ is ample but $H$ is not? Thanks!